# connection (proxy?) time-out after update

Tags: networking, internet, proxy

I have had an issue accessing journal articles through my campus since I updated to 17.04.  I'm assuming I'm connecting through some sort of proxy. Each i try  time I get a timeout error:

libproxy.wlu.ca took too long to respond.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

- My connection works fine otherwise
- The firewall is turned off.
- system settings -> network -> network proxy -> method is set to none.
- I don't need login credentials when on campus.
- I can connect to libproxy.wlu.ca when I boot windows, or I can ping it from the command prompt
  -I've cleared my cookies/cage  (I'm using chromium)

I'm thoroughly  network illiterate so apologise if this is vague.
Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being some sort of problem with dns resolution. Ultimately I deleted  /etc/resolv.conf and rebooted. This resolved the issue.